# Code is executed before PHPUnit's initialization

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage

I was reading my project's code coverage report, and I noticed something strange: a line was uncovered, but I was sure that line got executed during the tests. So, I added a **var_dump()** before it and this is what I got when executing the tests:

```
bool(true)
PHPUnit 3.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

...
```

This  is weird. How is it possible that a line is executed before PHPUnit's initialization? I believe this is the reason why code coverage says that line is uncovered.

Any hints?

EDIT: Here's some code. It's an IRC framework that makes use of the Doctrine Common library to read annotations and also uses the **ClassLoader** and **EventDispatcher** Symfony components. This is the incriminated method:

```
/**
 * Returns this module's reflection.
 * 
 * @return \ReflectionClass
 * @access public
 */
static public function getReflection()
{
    // The var_dump() displaying bool(false) is executed before PHPUnit, while the other
    // ones are correctly executed.
    var_dump(is_null(self::$reflection));

    if (null === self::$reflection) {
        // This line is reported as uncovered, but it must be executed since I'm
        // accessing the reflection!
        self::$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
    }

    return self::$reflection;
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: How can you say that is before PHPUnits initialization? It's only before PHPUnits output is written (the TextUI).

Comment: @hakre Then, why are all the others **var_dump()** (that method gets executed many times in the application) shown after PHPUnit's output? And why isn't that line reported in code coverage even if it's executed?

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, may I ask why you assign the `get_called_class` (which is late static binding) to `self::$...` and not `static::$...` ?

Comment: When does `getReflection()` get called?

Comment: It gets called in another static method which returns the events the module is subcribed to. I must use **ReflectionClass** because I use annotations to subscribe to events. This last static method is called in a test case. That's why I don't understand what's going on.

For what concerns the late static bind, that's my mistake. I'll correct it. Thanks.

Comment: For debugging purposes, enable xdebug stack traces (depending on your PHPUnit version, you might need to edit a file for that, see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/c812eb01a05aad271b4b99b3ef63e8f4714992e9) and then just throw an exception in that class to provoke the trace and stop executing. It should show you what's going on behind the scenes quite quickly. For example if the function is really called inside a test first *and not* before because of auto-loading or setting up the test.

Answer (score 1):

> Then, why are all the others var_dump() (that method gets executed many times in the application) shown after PHPUnit's output? And why isn't that line reported in code coverage even if it's executed?

I assume (but that's just a guess as it's hard to say since you have not shown the code), that it's related to code that gets executed on file-inclusion, rather after actual test functions are executed or testcases get instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

The accessor must be getting called outside of a unit test which initializes `self::$reflection`. After that, all further calls to `getReflection()` skip the `if` block so it'll never be counted as covered. PHPUnit instantiates all of the test case classes--one per test method, data provider method, and data provider argument array--before running any of the tests or tracing code coverage. Look for a test case that calls `getReflection()` from its constructor or outside the class itself where the code is executed upon loading.

I forget if the test cases are instantiated before PHPUnit outputs its version and cannot check now, but I believe this is the case. The other possibility is that you're calling `getReflection()` from `bootstrap.php`, but you probably already checked for that.